# Android NDK: 'modfl' was not declared in this scope

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to pull some code from another project into an NDK project, and when I build I'm getting the following error:

```
error: 'modfl' was not declared in this scope
```

In the source file I have `#import <math.h>` and the call is as follows:

```
long double tempValLong;
double tempValDouble; // This is initialized to a decimal number
long double n = modfl(tempValDouble , &tempValLong);
```

Application.mk includes `APP_STL := gnustl_static`.  Am I missing something, or does Android not include the modfl function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - #import is very non-standard directive in C/C++ code. You should use #include.

As for modfl - Android NDK doesn't have it. Most likely because of cross-platform issues. long double is not supported on ARM. You should use `double` instead of `long double` and use the `modf` function.

Comment: My mistake on the `#import`.  I must have spent too much time in Java :)

This gets me past my compilation issue.  Good explanation too.  Thanks!